# Git pull folders not present in Dev branch but keep other Dev folders unchange

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, git-pull, git-cherry-pick

I need help with some git pulling/merging

**2 branches: master and dev**

**Present states:**
State of folder0 and folder1 in master and dev = different
State of folder2 in master and dev = present in master, not present in dev

**Desired states of dev branch:**
State of folder0 and folder1 in dev = keep dev version
State of folder2 in dev = pull folder 2 that is not present in dev

I got some commands i have not seen before from GPT asking me to and need some help verifying this

```
git checkout dev
git checkout -b temp-branch
git cherry-pick <commit-hash-of-folder2-in-master>
git commit -m "Merge folder2 from master into dev"
git branch -d temp-branch
```

Thank you very much in advance